# Custom actions triggered by only app owner can generate stories

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-stream-story

I have created a fb app and added couple of custom actions and objects. If I login as myself and access the app ( click a button that executes a custom action ), it does generate the custom action story and shows up in the ticker on the right top section.  Also this story is visible to all the friends.

Life is good so far.

Now, when one of my friends does the same thing with his login, it does not create a story.
But I do see a story saying "xyz is using app abc" ... but nothing for the custom actions.

what could be going wrong ?  I checked the access token for my friends login using the facebook debugger, and it shows it as a valid token for my app.

realy appreciate some quick help pls !!

PS: The friend's id that I am using, is also admin of this app and his privacy settings for the app are set so that I am allowed to receive action updates from his activities.

Also the sandbox mode is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and debugging the app, found that it was actually throwing an error, indicating that the problem was with missing publish_actions permissions. I added those permissions requests in the scope, and boom ! It worked ! Logging it here with hope that it will help some one in future !

```
$dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($my_url)."&scope=publish_actions";
```